# How to make Foundation 5 top-bar submenu's inline?

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation, submenu

Is it possible to make subnav menu items under the Foundation 5 top-bar display inline/horizontally as compared to the default vertical stack?

I've been changing css properties in Chrome for hours to no avail and have been unable to locate and supporting documentation. Any help is appreciated.

I want to make this (default):
[image]

To this:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well assuming your html structure is like this - foundation structure for drodown men

```
 <li class="has-dropdown hover"><a href="#">Main Item 1</a>
     <ul class="dropdown">
          <li><a href="#">Dropdown Level 2a</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Dropdown Level 2b</a></li>
     </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

you must first change the width of the `ul dropdown` which is 100% - enough space to float the level2a and b

```
.top-bar-section .dropdown {width:xxx}
```

then you change the width of `ul dropdown li` which is also 100%  from to be smaller and float inside uldropdown

```
 .top-bar-section .dropdown li {width:xxx}
```

and viola!

Comment: Thanks @nol !!! ... I was able to get it to work best by setting `.dropdown li` to a width of auto. I was getting stuck on the 100% of the parent `.dropdown` class. Odd how 100% isn't 100% of the window.

Comment: I had to set `ul.dropdown{left: 1px;}` too!